# Find phrases from one text file in another text file with python

Tags: python

I have one file which is a list of phrases, one phrase on each line.
The other file is not delimitated in any way, it's just one huge text file of words. I want to search for the phrases in the second file and if they are found, to print the phrase. This is the code I have so far.

```
f = open("phrase.txt", "r")
g = open("text.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    search=line.lower()


for word in g:
    if search in word:
        print(search)
```

This is not printing anything for me, though.

EDIT: I changed the code to this:

```
f = open('phrase.txt').readlines()
f = [f.strip('\n').lower() for f in f]
g = open('text.txt').read()
for phrase in f:
    if phrase in g:
        print (phrase)
```

now i get the phrases that match. however some of the phrases have dashes (-) and more letters after them and they are not picked up by the program even if the phrase before the dash is present in text.txt. any way to change this?

Comment: try: `f = open("phrase.txt", "r").read() or f = open("phrase.txt", "r").readlines()  `

Comment: okay, i did .read() and it literally just printed the letter e and nothing else... any idea why that is?.readlines() returns nothing as well

Comment: are there spaces between the words in "text.txt"?

Comment: yes there are spaces, but all the words are on one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for every phrase in the file, you would have to nest the loops, currently, you are just searching for the last phrase

```
phrases = open("phrase.txt").readLines()

for phrase in phrases:
    search= phrase.lower()
    words = open("text.txt", "r")
    for word in words:
        if search in word:
            print(search)
    words.close()
```

However, now things start to look funny, because you are asking if a phrase is in a word, which doesn't seem right. So

```
phrases = open("phrase.txt").readLines()
words = open("text.txt").read()

for phrase in phrases:
    all_words_found = True
    phrase_words = phrase.lower().split(" ")
    for word in phrase_words:
        if word not in words:
            all_words_found = False
            break

    if all_words_found:
        print phrase
```

This is what you want I do believe

Comment: ah, yes you're right. I ran this code though, and it also didn't return anything

Comment: I edited it recently. Try it now. I didn't have time to actually test it

Comment: yep, still nothing! I put in some words i know are present in text.txt into phrase.txt and still nothing :(

Comment: With this algorithm, the phrase itself will have to be in text.txt in the exact form the phrase appears. The words of the phrase can't be scattered throughout text.txt

Comment: yeah, it just doesn't find the phrases even if they're exact. it doesn't print anything out

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('phrase.txt').readlines()
f = [f.strip('\n').lower() for f in f]
g = open('text.txt').read()
words = g.split()

for phrase in f:
    search_words = phrase.split()
    for word in search_words:
        if word in words:
            print phrase
```

Comment: @nat, I changed your variable names up a little bit, but try it out.

Comment: thanks! this works, but it only returns words and not the full phrases.

Comment: i changed it but i have no idea how to post code in comments

Comment: try the revised. I'm not exactly sure what your output is supposed to be, but maybe that'll do it.

Comment: This code isn't exactly right, it only checks it one of the words in the phrase is in text.txt, it can be easily modified though

Comment: @JDrost1818 yes, I changed it and edited my original question text. :)

Comment: @JDrost1818 wait, I didn't see this edit. how do i modify it?